# Created box with vagrant as root, want to run as normal user

Tags: macos, virtualbox, ruby, vagrant

I ran vagrant init/up as root initially with one of my boxes, however, all of my other boxes are owned by a normal user, so every time I want to use the box as a regular user, I have to sudo and then change the key ownership to login.

I have changed all of the permissions in ~/.vagrant.d/*, and the vagrant files themselves. How  can I access this box as non-root user? Is there another place I need to change permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Changing (or setting) the `config.ssh.username = "vagrant"` line in your Vagrantfile will allow you to ssh into another user account assuming it exists. You can also use `vagrant ssh -p' which allows you to manually enter the authentication credentials you would like to use each time you ssh into the box.